# My container or row is in the middle of the page content and not sticking at the bottom of the page like footer widgets are supposed to

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code I've pulled.  I don't know how to push the footer widget down to the bottom of the page.  The footer sits at the bottom for other pages because there isn't a lot of content but on one page, it sits in the middle of the content.

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="footer-widget-area" class="row">
        <div class="footer-widgets-1 col-md-12"></div>
      </div>
      <aside id="black-studio-tinymce-4" class="widget_black_studio_tinymce widget well">
        <div class="textwidget">
          <h6 style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="color: #000000;">© 2016 xxxx LLC | Location| Phone Number | email@gmail.com</span>
            <br>
            <em>
              <span style="color: #000000;"> All photos, designs, layouts, and content on this website, including blog, are under copyright, unless otherwise noted. If you would like to borrow an image and/or content, kindly request for permission.</span>
            </em>
          </h6>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="site-info"></div>
        <div class="attribution">
          <span class="attribution-theme-mods">
            <a href="http://www.website.com/attribution/">Special Thanks</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

The attribution, display none is for WordPress attribution that I don't want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

http://jsbin.com/qepuxay/edit?html,css,output

Critical CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 140px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Note: this requires that the height of the footer is 'known' - I have set it to 140px, with 140px added as padding to body. I have also added a red border-top for visual purposes.

Comment: Do I add this to the css?  And if so, is this within .site-footer selector or on its own? Thanks for your help

Comment: I haven't modified your HTML - just add the CSS above to your existing CSS, it should work.

Comment: Just tried it and the code works but on smaller screens, the text (and red border box) is still in the middle of the page.

Comment: I haven't tried it in jsbin, just in CSS because that's the only place I know where to post.  Would it not work in just posting in CSS?

Comment: Is there a vertical align element I can add to make this footer stick to the bottom?  That seems to be issue for smaller screens.

Comment: I've only seen a small block of your HTML, and none of your CSS. I posted a link in my answer, if you can view that link, and the footer sits at the bottom of the page there, then the only remaining task is for you to copy the CSS from my answer to your CSS.

Comment: Yes I saw the css you posted in the link and copied the css into my styesheet but the container row box is still sitting in the middle of the page on smaller screens.

Comment: You'll need to post more code, including your CSS. My code sets the `footer` to sit at the bottom, which is the code you posted in your question.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the height of the row and where it is being placed on the page.  On pages with smaller content, it sits at the bottom but with one page that has so much content, it sits in the middle.   I am not sure how to adjust the row (or contaianer)

Comment: Would you be willing to chat with me for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create a chat because I don't have the 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk on chat.  :-/

Comment: Do you know another way to post css code on here without going over in characters?

Comment: I'd seriously look into using CodePen, JSBin or JSFiddle. That way you can work on code, then post a link for a full example (while still posting relevant code in questions). You're far more likely to get high quality answers that way.

Comment: I was able to determine that the widget I am using for visual editor to create my footer (for copyright information) is causing all the problems.  Now I need to figure out how to make that widget sit at the bottom of the page.